# wxpython: adding a Listctrl group

Tags: wxpython, wxwidgets

Since Windows XP, there has been a feature called the ListView group which allows you to separate your data into logical groups.

[image: Listview group]

I haven't been able to find anything like this in the wxpython or wxwidget documentation for this. Is it possible to implement or do I have to write something for this myself?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The module ObjectListView has a [GroupListView](http://objectlistview.sourceforge.net/python/groupListView.html#using-grouplistview).

Comment: Thanks Yoriz, this was close to what I needed